# history-search-backward and history-incremental-search-backward

Tags: zsh

When I run `bindkey -L` I see the followings:

```
...
bindkey "^R" history-incremental-search-backward
...
bindkey "^[n" history-search-forward
```

What is the difference between them?
When I try them I can't find any difference.

Answer (score 0):

`^R` and `^S` are *incremental,* which means they will show you the next matching history item *as you type.*

`^[p` and `^[n`, on the other hand, simply cycle through history items that match what you've already typed.

Comment: ESC-p and ESC-n seems to search only the first word not what you've already typed.